# Como fazer uma pesquisa like em laravel 5.5 usando o relacionamento eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

eu preciso fazer uma pesquisa usando o like em uma model que tem relacionamento com outra tabela(equipamentos). O que tem acontecido é que está trazendo todos os registros da tabela ordemservicos com a tabela relacionada nula (equipamentos) e num dos registros vem o equipamento relacionado. Não está conseguindo usar o where. Podem me ajudar?
Fui claro?

Vejam:

```
    $pesquisa = $dataForm['pesquisa'];
    //dd($pesquisa);
    $data = Ordemservico::with([
        'equipamento' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
            $query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', '%117%');
        },
    ])->get();
    dd($data);
```

Deixei o 117 fixo mas mesmo assim traz todas as ordens de serviço!.

Obrigado

Comment: Coloque o exemplo das duas tabelas e seus respectivos Model

Comment: $fillable = ['codigoequipamento', 'descricaoequipamento', 'centrocusto_id', 'tipoequipamento_id', 
        'tipogas_id', 'local_id', 'tipolocal_id', 'fornecedor_id', 'fabricante_id', 'modelo', 'patrimonio', 'numeroserie', 
        'dataaquisicao', 'notafical', 'valoraquisicao', 'dataagarantia', 'tag', 'btu', 'tr', 'hp', 'ativo'];
    public function rules($id = '')
    {
        return [
          'codigoequipamento'       => 'required|min:3|max:25',
          'descricaoequipamento'    => 'required|min:1|max:190',
          'tag'                     => 'required|min:1|max:190',

Comment: class Ordemservico extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'colaborador_id', 'centrocusto_id', 'local_id', 'tiposolicitacao_id', 'dataplanejamento',
       'dataencerramento', 'tiposervico_id', 'checklist_id', 'descricaopadrao', 'prioridade_id', 'equipe1', 'equipe2', 
       'equipamento_id', 'equipe_id', 'descricaoservico', 'dataultimaexecucao', 'periodicidade', 
       'frequencia_id', 'impedimento_id', 'dataexecucao', 'anexo'];

Comment: $pesquisa = $dataForm['pesquisa'];
        //dd($pesquisa);
        $data = Ordemservico::whereHas([
            'equipamento' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
                $query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', "%$pesquisa%");
            },
            'local',
            'tiposolicitacao',
        ])->get();

Comment: na sua pergunta! edite a sua pergunta e coloque tudo isso lá!

Comment: talvez aqui mora o problema `$query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', '%117%');` porque esse filtro, esse codigoequipamento é a chave da relação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso, você deve usar `whereHas` e não `with`.

Existem uma diferença entre os dois:

- `whereHas` -> Você usa quando quer que resultado da sua consulta seja alterado pela condição passada no relacionamento.
- `with`  -> É usado para carregar antecipadamente os relacionamentos. Quando se usa uma função anônima, retorna os relacionamentos de acordo com a consulta passada dentro dela.

Mude sua consulta para:

```
OrdemServico::whereHas('equipamento', static function ($query) {
    $query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', '%117%');
})
->get();
```

Comment: está dando um erro:
"strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Fiz assim:
        $pesquisa = $dataForm['pesquisa'];
        //dd($pesquisa);
        $data = Ordemservico::whereHas([
            'equipamento' => static function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
                $query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', "%$pesquisa%");
            },
            'local',
            'tiposolicitacao',
        ])->get();

Tem algo errado?

Comment: Não entendi como isso tem relação à pergunta que foi feita anteriormente. Por favor, caso tenha surgido outro problema, considere fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Quando eu troquei para whereHas passou a dar este erro:
"strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: Você trocou pelo `whereHas` ou fez como está no código da minha resposta? O `whereHas` espera `string` no primeiro parâmetro, e não um `array`

Comment: Eu só troquei para o whereHas
Sim, eu tirei o array com os outros relacionamentos, deixei só o relacionamento com equipamento e funcionou mas preciso colocar os outros relacionamentos. Se não pode ser num array, como devo colocar?

Comment: @MarcosBirro olha a resposta, cara. Eu coloquei do jeito que você deve fazer :\

Comment: Você me disse para fazer assim:
OrdemServico::whereHas('equipamento', static function ($query) {
    $query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', '%117%');
})
->get();
Eu fiz mas preciso dos outros relacionamentos. Como devo colocar os outros relacionamentos?
Agora
            $pesquisa = $dataForm['pesquisa'];
            //dd($pesquisa);
            $ordemservicos = Ordemservico::whereHas(
                'equipamento', static function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
                    $query->where('codigoequipamento', 'LIKE', "%$pesquisa%");
                })->get();
Assim funciona

Comment: Como eu disse: `whereHas` afeta a consulta de acordo com a condição do relacionamento, já o `with` carrega os relacionamentos. Você pode usar os dois juntos

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou como eu queria.
Obrigado.